# Kernel crash when simplifying piecewise function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, crash

So the kernel appears to just die whenever you try to simplify a piecewise function containing "Nothing".  For example: this appears to kill the kernel

> $$\text{Simplify@}\begin{array}{cc} \Bigl[\begin{array}{cc} x & x=5 \\   \text{Nothing} & \text{True} \\  \end{array} \end{array}$$

Has anyone else encountered this?  Is there a workaround?

Mathematica version 11.2, running on Windows 10.

Copy-pasteable code:

```
Simplify@ \!\(\*
TagBox[GridBox[{
{"\[Piecewise]", GridBox[{
{"x", 
RowBox[{"x", "==", "5"}]},
{"Nothing", 
TagBox["True",
"PiecewiseDefault",
AutoDelete->True]}
},
AllowedDimensions->{2, Automatic},
Editable->True,
GridBoxAlignment->{
         "Columns" -> {{Left}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
          "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxItemSize->{
         "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
          "Rows" -> {{1.}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.84]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
Selectable->True]}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{
      "Columns" -> {{Left}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
       "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxItemSize->{
      "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
       "Rows" -> {{1.}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.35]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}}],
"Piecewise",
DeleteWithContents->True,
Editable->False,
SelectWithContents->True,
Selectable->False]\)
```

Comment: copyable code: `Simplify[Piecewise[{{x, x == 5}, {Nothing, True}}]]`. I confirm this crashes the kernel (10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)).

Comment: Is it because of the Nothing?